# Forwarding resolves to another container

Tags: c#, structuremap

For historic reasons, our application has a single static StructureMap `Container` which is used for all IoC/DI everywhere. We have quite a few tests which check that this container is properly set up, but it is becoming increasingly difficult to ensure that tests don't interfere with each other. I would like to start breaking out to several (non-static) containers to alleviate this. To retain backward compatibility, things configured in this container must be available from the main container still.

I have implemented a proof-of-concept for a small part of the system which handles only a few base types this way:

```
_pocContainer = new Container(/* setup code */);
MainContainer.Configure(c => c.For<C>.Use(ctx => _pocContainer.GetInstance<C>());
```

This works, and when requesting an instance of `C` from the static container, it is resolved from the `_pocContainer`. However, I'm fairly certain that this isn't something that was considered a normal use case when designing StructureMap. Will this cause bad performance, or have any other negative consequences? Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you divide the registration into Registries and test each Registry separately?

Comment: @PHeiberg: Good idea! Implemented it this way - please post as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to divide the registration into `Registries` and test each registry separately.

```
public class FooRegistry : Registry {
    public FooRegistry() {
        For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
    }
}
```

You can then explicitly use the registry in the test

```
var container = new Container(new FooRegistry());
```

But have all registries automatically scanned in your composition root

```
var container = new Container(x => {
    x.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.TheCallingAssembly()
       scanner.LookForRegistries();
    });
});
```